# Wordpress media upload creates new folders as root user

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress default upload file structure,

`public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/`

but on the 1st day of each month it creates a new folder as root user (e.g.`public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/`), I had to manually change its ownership to `www-data`.

Why is it using root to create folders? Can I do something to change it?

Comment: Follow [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) guide to harden file/folder permissions for wordpress

Comment: This might be a very late comment. But we are experiencing this problem right now. Every new month Wordpress creates a new folder in the uploads/2019/xx with the owner root:root. We have to manually chown username:username every month, after that everything works. (centos 7). Did you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @NMENewMediaEntertainment same here, did you find any solution?